# Move and Resize Overlapping 16:9 Aspect Ratio Images

Tags: javascript, html, css

SOLVED (I think) -- See Below.

Quick Background: For a simple IOS game I have 16:9 background area that I am floating images over top of that need to blend into the background.  For that, I need them to resize with the background and move with the background.

Hypothesis: I'm keeping the game area 16:9 because I assume that will scale well with various devices.  If I also make the images that need to float on top of the background 16:9, they should scale at the same rate and provide a steady % scale to also move them in place.

Test: I have a background area of 1280x720, with a slice cut out 256x144(20%).  I have an image of 256x144 that I'm trying to overlay that slice, which sometimes works, but doesn't always respond well to resizing or doesn't line up on various devices.  Is my math somehow wrong?

Here's the code: [JS Fiddle: Testing Image Overlap](https://jsfiddle.net/mikecruz/tfzwekhu/)

- SOLVED - 
  I was incorrectly assuming that the width of the floated image and the % it needed to be moved was based on a % of the window width (as is the case with the container DIV) to maintain it's 16:9 ratio, but the incorrect results occurred when the 16:9 ratio of the container maxed out at less than the screen width.  What I actually want is the image nested into the container and use a % of that parent instead of the window! Can't believe I missed that for hours...

New Code (Hope this will help someone): [Updated Fiddle - Proper Image Scaling](https://jsfiddle.net/mikecruz/bw2fsj43/)

```css
<style>
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#Game_Wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vw * 9 / 16);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
    left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: lightblue url('https://i.imgur.com/BFCIQuw.png') center/contain no-repeat;
}
#Game_Area {
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
#GUI_Top {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 30px;
 background: grey;
}
#GUI_Top p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#GUI_Bottom {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 30px;
 background: grey;
}
#GUI_Bottom p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;"
}
/* 100 * 16/9 = 177.778 */
@media (min-width: 177.778vh) {
    #Game_Wrapper {
        height: 100vh;
        width: calc(100vh * 16 / 9);
    }
}
.Building_Position {
    width: calc(100vw * .2);
    height: calc(100vh * .2);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#Building1 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100vw * .40);
    top: calc(100vh * .20);
}
#Building1 img {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
    width: calc(100vw * .20);
    height: calc(100vh * .20);

}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Test Game Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="Game_Wrapper">
  <!-- This will hold the entire game and GUI -->
  <div id="GUI_Top">
   <!-- This is where the top GUI will be -->
            <p>This is the top GUI / NAV</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Game_Area">
   <!-- This is where you can interact with the actual game -->
  </div>
  <div id="GUI_Bottom">
   <!-- This is where the bottom GUI will be -->
   <p>This is the bottom GUI / NAV</p>
  </div>
        <div class="Building_Position" id="Building1">
            <a href="#Link To Function" alt="Building Name" title="Building Name & Level" class="load_view">
                <img class="building_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/dqEFcAu.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how your expected output would look like?

Comment: The green box should overlap and be the same size as the blue one in the code fiddle example and stick with it on screen resize.

Comment: Notice, that `#` selector will override the common properties set with `.` selector.

Comment: Oh man! I see the problem.  One sec... Yes, also I took the floated image out of the game area because it was giving some strange actions, which I assumed had to do with something strange being inherited.   In fact, that's what I want..

Comment: @MikeCruz13 I've found [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) a handy way to solve this kind of calculations, if nothing else, using variables makes the CSS simpler, and it's whole lot easier to make changes.